# How to delete history lines when browsing history with fzf

Tags: bash, command-history

There are often items in the bash history which I don't need anymore and/or are so long that when used with fzf match pretty much any text entered, making fuzzy matching on the history a bit useless. So I was looking for a way to be able to delete these lines when viewing history with fzf, but this is too naive (plus misses reloading, but that's not the issue here):

```
export FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS="--bind 'ctrl-d:execute-silent(history -d {1})'"
```

It doesn't delete any history and I am assuming that might be because fzf runs the command like `$SHELL -c "history -d 1000"` but that is a new shell (my $SHELL is /bin/bash) which has no history (or at least not the one from the current shell). Is that assumption correct? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

One approach (shown below as an alias to be put in your .bashrc) is to edit the .bash_history file directly, using fzf to select commands, then after editing, reload it:

```
alias histfzf='history -w; cat .bash_history | fzf > /tmp/to_remove; grep -vxFf /tmp/to_remove .bash_history > .new_bash_history; mv .new_bash_history .bash_history; rm /tmp/to_remove; history -r'
```

Explanation of each step:

```
# write active history in memory to the .bash_history file
history -w;

# select commands from history (using fzf), and store them in a file:
cat .bash_history | fzf > /tmp/to_remove

# Find commands that don't appear in the to_remove list (and store in .new_bash_history:
grep -vxFf /tmp/to_remove .bash_history > .new_bash_history

# overwrite the history with the edited version:
mv .new_bash_history .bash_history;

# clean up:
rm /tmp/to_remove;

# reload history:
history -r
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The whole of it is not really what I'm looking for (I really want to modify history without leaving fzf and then just continue selecting what I actaully want) but it got me started, see answer

Comment: For zsh, you need to use `zsh_history`
`alias histfzf='history -w; cat .zsh_history | fzf -m > /tmp/to_remove; grep -vxFf /tmp/to_remove .zsh_history > .new_zsh_history; mv .new_zsh_history .zsh_history; rm /tmp/to_remove; history -r'`

and I added `-m` to enable multi mode which you can select multiple entries with `tab` so you can delete multiple commands with single command

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to mattb's idea I'm currently using this in .bashrc, comments added.

```
# Separate so that should fzf's __fzf_history__ implementation change I can just copy-paste
# from it into this file without having to put my stuff in between.
# {+f2..} = fzf will replace this with path to a file containing
#           all selected items starting at second field i.e. the actual history text
export FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS="--bind 'ctrl-s:clear-selection,ctrl-d:execute-silent(grep -vxFf {+f2..} ~/.bash_history > ~/.edh; cp ~/.edh ~/.bash_history)'"

__fzf_history__() {
  # Flush to .bash_history
  history -w
  # Same as in fzf's original implementation, except that +m is replaced with -m
  # to allow selection of multiple items.
  local output
  output=$(
    builtin fc -lnr -2147483648 |
      last_hist=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT='' builtin history 1) perl -n -l0 -e 'BEGIN { getc; $/ = "\n\t"; $HISTCMD = $ENV{last_hist} + 1 } s/^[ *]//; print $HISTCMD - $. . "\t$_" if !$seen{$_}++' |
      FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--height ${FZF_TMUX_HEIGHT:-60%} $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS -n2..,.. --tiebreak=index --bind=ctrl-r:toggle-sort,ctrl-z:ignore $FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS -m --read0" $(__fzfcmd) --query "$READLINE_LINE"
  )
  # Reload from .bash_history if needed.
  if [ -f ~/.edh ]; then
    history -r
    rm ~/.edh
  fi
  # Rest of original implementation
  if [ -z "$output"]; then
    return
  fi
  READLINE_LINE=${output#*$'\t'}
  if [ -z "$READLINE_POINT" ]; then
    echo "$READLINE_LINE"
  else
    READLINE_POINT=0x7fffffff
  fi
}

# CTRL-R - Paste the selected command from history into the command line
bind -m emacs-standard -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
bind -m vi-command -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
bind -m vi-insert -x '"\C-r": __fzf_history__'
```

Does everything I want, except reloading the view but that would require putting most of that massive command in the fzf commandline so I'm not going there right now :)

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that might be useful to keep your bash history free of non-useful
commands is to set the `HISTIGNORE` variable in your .bashrc:

```
HISTIGNORE="cd:cl:clc:ls:l:ll:lll:..:...:....:sob:f *"
```

Each command that you don't want recorded in your history is separated by a
colon. You can also use regexp patterns to filter out the commands.

Many of the commands I filter out are aliases I have that I never search back
to repeat:

```
# clear the terminal (clc is because I did too much matlab)
alias cl='clear && clear'
alias clc='clear && clear'

# show ls vertically by default using the -1 switch
alias l='ls -1 -hF'
# same as above, but with file details too
alias ll='ls -lhF'
# same as above, but with hidden files too
alias lll='ls -alhF'

# move up 1,2 or 3 directories
alias ..='cd ../'
alias ...='cd ../../'
alias ....='cd ../../../'

# source .bashrc
alias sob='source ~/.bashrc'
```

The last command `f *` is a function I wrote ([see answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963660/how-to-open-a-file-in-a-specific-application-from-fzf/64416946#64416946)) to use fzf
to select files from around my system and pass them as arguments to any program
(e.g. vim, cat, vlc, evince etc.). When I first wrote it, my history would be
full of things like `f vim` and `f cd` - completely useless to me later. I've
since improved the function so that it actually puts the fzf expanded command
into history, so I don't need to filter `f *` now, but it helps illustrate the
use of regexp to ignore certain commands.

In case they fzf function I mentioned interests you, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run command/application and choose paths/files with fzf.
# Always return control of the terminal to user (e.g. when opening GUIs).
# The full command that was used will appear in your history just like any
# other (N.B. to achieve this I write the shell's active history to
# ~/.bash_history)
#
# Usage:
# f cd [OPTION]... (hit enter, choose path)
# f cat [OPTION]... (hit enter, choose files)
# f vim [OPTION]... (hit enter, choose files)
# f vlc [OPTION]... (hit enter, choose files)

f() {
    # Store the program
    program="$1"

    # Remove first argument off the list
    shift

    # Store option flags with separating spaces, or just set as single space
    options="$@"
    if [ -z "${options}" ]; then
        options=" "
    else
        options=" $options "
    fi

    # Store the arguments from fzf
    arguments=($(fzf --multi))

    # If no arguments passed (e.g. if Esc pressed), return to terminal
    if [ -z "${arguments}" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    # We want the command to show up in our bash history, so write the shell's
    # active history to ~/.bash_history. Then we'll also add the command from
    # fzf, then we'll load it all back into the shell's active history
    history -w

    # ADD A REPEATABLE COMMAND TO THE BASH HISTORY ############################
    # Store the arguments in a temporary file for sanitising before being
    # entered into bash history
    : > /tmp/fzf_tmp
    for file in "${arguments[@]}"; do
        echo "$file" >> /tmp/fzf_tmp
    done

    # Put all input arguments on one line and sanitise the command by putting
    # single quotes around each argument, also first put an extra single quote
    # next to any pre-existing single quotes in the raw argument
    sed -i "s/'/''/g; s/.*/'&'/g; s/\n//g" /tmp/fzf_tmp

    # If the program is on the GUI list, add a '&' to the command history
    if [[ "$program" =~ ^(nautilus|zathura|evince|vlc|eog|kolourpaint)$ ]]; then
        sed -i '${s/$/ \&/}' /tmp/fzf_tmp
    fi

    # Grab the sanitised arguments
    arguments="$(cat /tmp/fzf_tmp)"

    # Add the command with the sanitised arguments to our .bash_history
    echo $program$options$arguments >> ~/.bash_history

    # Reload the ~/.bash_history into the shell's active history
    history -r

    # EXECUTE THE LAST COMMAND IN ~/.bash_history #############################
    fc -s -1

    # Clean up temporary variables
    rm /tmp/fzf_tmp
}
```

Comment: Problem with HISTIGNORE is that if you make a typo you cannot use e.g. up arrow to get that command back (my workaround would be binding ctrl-enter to prepending a space to the current line to exclude form history because I have HISTOGNORE=ignorespace, then add to kill ring, then execute, so in case of typo it can be yanked back). Your `f` function is roughly the same as standard fzf tab completion no? E.g. `cd **` followed by TAB starts fzf to browse for directories.

Comment: Ah yes that's true about the typos, I suppose I don't often use very long commands in the terminal - I usually write them in vim and use :w !bash to execute them.

Comment: Yes I'm not completely sure what the reasoning was behind not just expanding `**` for everything; that's basically how I use it all the time in powershell: I have Ctrl-P bound to 'start fzf with previous token as start dir or if no dir given then start from current directory, then insert selection onto commandline'

Comment: And thanks for the link - I don't use bash often enough to warrant the time to learn it inside out so always good to have properly commented examples :)

Comment: @stijn After some experimentation, the `cd **` appears to  do the same thing but only in the current directory - or you have to type out the path to where you want fzf to search. I configured my fzf to search several directories on a VIP list (https://superuser.com/questions/1629223/how-to-start-fzf-from-another-directory-than-the-current-working-directory/1640499#1640499), rather than defaulting to the current directory. The `f` function respects that so I can do `f cd` and just start typing to get to where I want, rather than `path/to/dir **` + `Tab`.

Comment: My PR might interest you then https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/pull/2447 :)

Comment: @stijn Ah nice yes I hope that PR gets accepted soon! Would I be able to select my home directory as root? Then I would just need a way to blacklist/whitelist certain directories in my home directory and I wouldn't need the f function at all!

Comment: Yes exactly, works with any directory. I've been using it locally for a while just like that.